# How do I calculate a specific price fee?

Tags: python, paypal

I made a post about this previously,  but I feel I worded/explained it wrong. I'll show you the code then I'll give an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
amountPaid = float(input("Enter the amount you're paying:\n"))
taxPercentage = float(input("Enter the tax percentage:\n"))

taxPercentage = taxPercentage / 100
firstFee = (amountPaid * taxPercentage) + .30
newAmount = amountPaid - firstFee
secondFee = (newAmount * taxPercentage) + .30
total = secondFee + newAmount
print("{:.2f}".format(total))
while total < amountPaid:
  newAmount = newAmount + .01
print("The amount you should be paying is ${:.2f}".format(total))
print("The fee with that total would be ${:.2f}".format(secondFee))
```

(Note) The above code actually currently doesn't work, I believe it's the `while` statement but it gives you an idea.

It should be pretty apparent that I'm quite new to programming, so any beginner tips you can give would also be appreciated.

What I'm trying to do is calculate a fee to equal a precise total, like so:

- Let's say I'm paying $1.00. The fee to that payment, using the above equation, would equal $1.33.
- So if you subtracted that $0.33 fee from the initial $1.00 that we started with, we'd get $0.67
- But, the fee of $0.67 is $0.32, which would be $0.99, not precisely $1.00

I did my best to explain this as thoroughly as possible, but if you have any questions please ask, it's bothering me that I can't figure this out haha.

Comment: Why are you subtracting fees? I wish Comcast would do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick point is that your while loop depends on two variables: `amountPaid` and `total`. This means that the while loop will loop forever if those two do not change, so you have to make sure that they are being modified **within the loop**.

You can also quickly see that the loop itself does not modify either of those two, it only modifies `newAmount`. That means the loop will run forever, or not at all, so in this scenario it is useless.

So you need to change where variables are being modified. Note that when you write:

```
total = secondFee + newAmount
```

it is not a **definition** that will stay true at all times, instead, it is an **assignment**. That means that modifying `secondFee` and `newAmount` will not directly modify `total` unless you rewrite that same line. (Note that this is what a loop does, it "rewrites lines"!)

Back to your code: at the moment, only those two options are possible. With a quick look at your code, it looks like you meant to put these two lines in the while loop:

```
while total < amountPaid:
    newAmount = newAmount + .01
    secondFee = (newAmount * taxPercentage) + .30
    total = secondFee + newAmount
```

I hope you can understand why, and good luck to all your future programming endeavours :)

Comment: PS: some programming languages actually do use sorts of "definitions", instead of assignment. Maybe in the future you'll check those out.

Comment: I got it working thanks to you! I really appreciate your help (: I'll definitely look into the different sorts of definitions soon.

What I did was instead of doing `while total < amountPaid:`

I did `while (secondFee + newAmount) <= amountPaid:`